# Limit graphql-codegen by kind

Tags: graphql, graphql-codegen

I am using graphql-codegen to generate types for an internal package to allow graph queries to interact with a *very* small subset of the massive schema of a larger application.

The stitched-schema has identically named objects of different kinds, which is resulting in invalid TypeScript as it generating identically named objects.

The duplicate named objects in stitched-schema.json have kinds “INPUT_OBJECT” and “OBJECT”.

Is there a way to filter to only generate for a specific kind, split the generated files by source .graphql/generated .tsx document or otherwise limit the generated types to only those in the documents defined in the plugin and thus queries/mutations/subscriptions we actually require.

The preference would be to exclude types for unrelated queries as this would cut the generated code from many thousand lines to just over hundred.

Omitting the typescript plugin gets me most of the way there, but it is missing Exact, Scalars and the response type definitions.

The best I can think of for now is to switch overwrite to false and manually add the missing types. Is there a better way to filter generated types through some kind of predicate and allow me to keep the package in sync with application changes.

This is our current (obfuscated) configuration-

```
overwrite: false
schema: "http://localhost:3000/graph"
documents: ["src/graphql/QueryOne.graphql", "src/graphql/QueryTwo.graphql", "src/graphql/QueryThree.graphql"]
config:
  withHooks: true
  reactApolloVersion: 3
generates:
  "./src/lib/graphql.tsx":
    plugins:
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-apollo"
```

Comment: why do you need to have types with the same name? can you use more unique names across your project? does it solve you problem to list only the necessary files in `documents`?

Comment: The code I am writing and responsible for is external to the application whose schema it is consuming and whose application it calls. Whilst I _might_ be able to push for changes to that application eventually, for the purposes of this question it is a black box I cannot control. I only have the three queries I actually need in documents, is there a way to stop it generating types for the entire schema? Apart from anything else, this seems incredibly inefficient and wasteful.

Comment: Thankfully for me, the issue does not occur in any of the queries I actually do need to consume.